# Typing jQuery plugin needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need a jQuery plugin to create type effect. Is there anyone or should I write one myself?

Comment: Write it and share it. Whatever it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this what you mean? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tickertype

Answer (score 1):

[`Create-a-typing-text-effect-using-jquery`](http://www.thepixelart.com/create-a-typing-text-effect-using-jquery/) plugin might help you. You might need to customize this plugin to suit your requirement.